# How can I choose which Google Drive backup WhatsApp uses?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

I have two phones with WhatsApp.

I have a WhatsApp backup on one Google account, and one on another.

Is there any way to choose which Google Drive backup to use, without removing all but one Google account?

Comment: To clarify, did you mean to restore the backup from which Google account, or to store the backup to which Google account?

Comment: @AndrewT. well, if an answer covers both then even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can't

From [WhatsApp FAQ](https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000019/?category%3D5245251&hl=en-IN)

> In order to successfully restore a Google Drive backup, you need to use the **same phone number and Google account used to create the backup**

(Emphasis added)